# Using GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE and writing to the alpha channel

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

So I have a question about if there is a way to get a correct alpha result when drawing something with alpha to coverage in OpenGL. I am drawing some stuff in a buffer that is going to be composited on top of a video, so it is writing to a black transparent buffer and the un-premultiplying it to composite

However some of the objects are drawn with Alpha to Coverage. The issue is that in order for the coverage resolve to produce the correct alpha value for each of the samples, the alpha of the sample needs to be 1. But the alpha that is output is for example 0.75 writing to a transparent backing, in order for alpha to coverage to work, and if you write 0.75 to the alpha, it will then average 0.75 among the samples to give 0.5625.

So basically i'm wondering if there is some way to output and alpha of 1 to the samples I am writing to, or if not is there another way to achieve the result I want (Ideally still using alpha to coverage because I need the order independent transparency)

I don't mind using super modern opengl stuff or nvidia extensions for this due to the very specific hardware requirements

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out - there is
GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_ONE
which does exactly what I want - sets the alpha to the max value no matter what you output

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).